# Change Language as a user preferance in React Native App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-ios

I am creating an app using React Native and need the ability to change the app's language "on the fly" so to speak. I have followed the sample here: https://github.com/appfoundry/react-native-multi-language-sample. After following this I have successfully setup Redux and all of the accompanying libraries.

The issue I'm having is that I'm trying to trigger my action from an alert popup not a picker and I'm having issues actually dispatching the action.

If anyone can show me how to change the user language using an Alert that would be fantastic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on a situation that maybe the idea can help you.

I used `react-native-i18n` (https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n) and created a file with all my translations. Something like this:

```
I18n.translations = {
  en: {
    helloWorld: 'Hello World!',
    loginButton: 'Login',
  }
}
```

Then I imported it in my component which contains the texts that should be translated and use it like this:

```
<View>
  <Text>{I18n.t('helloWorld'}</Text>
</View>
```

I have the user language stored in my database and I get it and set in my reducer when user logs in in my app. At first I get the languge from `I18n.currentLocale()` method.

In my component I get the user language from my reducer and set it on I18n config:
`I18n.locale = this.props.language;`

In this component I have a picker so user can select its language. I trigger an action to update my database, as well the reducer and use `componentWillReceiveProps()` lifecycle to update `I18n.locale` value

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    I18n.locale = nextProps.language;
  }
```

Hope it helps