# Change Multiple Languages from Setting on User Selection in React Native

Tags: react-native, redux, localization

I want to change my language of app in setting on user selection base like below.

[image: User Selection]

. I have followed [Multi-language support on github](https://github.com/vikrantnegi/react-native-multi-language-app) .

But the problem is that

> My App changing language on device base language   not on my user selection
>   base.

What i want is to change it thought my User selection base  through redux.

i have seen below question on stack but didn't get enough concept to solve my problem.

[Change Language as a user preferance in React Native App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493150/change-language-as-a-user-preferance-in-react-native-app)

i have also read https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize

Anyone can help to implement this type of scenario in react native ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here [GITHUBREPO](https://github.com/hiaw/rn-translate-template) is a good example implemented in using the lib aka localizer/ I18n

The main idea here is to minimize the memory required of other languages that are not used by the platform.

For example, if the phone is localized in French, then this will only load the French and English translations into memory and ignore the 30+ other languages available.

Comment: that's cool.               what if  i want if user toggle useArabic   then app language change to Arabic . ?       how can i do this ?         in I18n.js   switch language is available but how to swtich from toggling from setting ?

Comment: The question is regarding  change language based upon user settings, not how to optimize the language loading based on default settings